# Set height of UITableViewCell by height of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a problem: I have `UITableView` with `UITableViewCell`, at cell I have `UICollectionView` with a different number `UICollectionViewCell`. I want to `UITableViewCell` height corresponds to the height of `UICollectionView`. 
I see real height `UICollectionView` here:

```
    class TimeViewCell: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet weak var labelTime: UILabel!

        var dataForShow = [String]() {

            didSet{
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            }
        }

        @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!



        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()

            collectionView.delegate = self
            collectionView.dataSource = self

        }

    }

    extension TimeViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            return dataForShow.count
        }


        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionCell

            cell.labelCollection.text = dataForShow[indexPath.row]

            let realValueHeightOfCollection = collectionView.contentSize.height

//when print realValueHeightOfCollection I see 50.0 (if dataForShow.count <4) or 110.0 (if dataForShow.count >5)

            return cell
        }

    }
```

but how to pass that height to height `UITableViewCell`?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellTime", for: indexPath) as! TimeViewCell
    let showHour = self.infoWripper.sorted(by: { $0.hour < $1.hour })[indexPath.row]

    cell.labelTime.text = showHour.showHour()

    cell.dataForShow = showHour.showFullTime()


    //here may be set the height of cell?

    return cell
}
```

upd Storyboard: [image]

Comment: use `uitableviewautomaticdimension` in `heightOfrow` method.

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy where?

Comment: Is every `UITableViewCell` height is same or variable ??

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy `UITableViewCell` contains `UICollectionView`. `UICollectionView` contains some `UICollectionViewCell`. If count of `UICollectionViewCell` < 3 height standard, but I want dynamic cell, because count `UICollectionViewCell` may be 10. Now height is same

Comment: Show me your `storyboard` work.

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy I added screenshot, please, look at that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided my problem by adding one line:

```
tableTime.rowHeight = cell.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
```

in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {...}`

Answer (score 2):

I Have an approach for you:
I used this in my code and m sharing with you

in TableView height method:

```
// MARK: - TableView Delegate Methods:
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        var height: CGFloat = 0.0
        //   //  //print("arrTA[indexPath.row] = \(arrTA[indexPath.row])")
        let dict = arrTA[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
        let str = dict[ISSELECTED] as! String
        let strFlage = dict[FLAGE] as! String
        let arrFileCount = dict[DATA]!["file_list"] as! NSArray//dict.objectForKey(DATA)?.objectForKey("file_list").count as NSMutableArray

        if(strFlage == "MA") {

            height = 50.0

        } else {
             height = self.setExpandedViewHeight(arrFileCount.count) + 0.0                
        }
        return height
    }
```

And I used this function in managing height:

```
func setExpandedViewHeight(intArrCount: Int) -> CGFloat {
        var height: CGFloat = 0.0
        var generatedHeight: Int = 0

        generatedHeight = intArrCount / 3 /// We get number of rows

        if(intArrCount % 3 == 0) {

            height =  CGFloat(generatedHeight) * 100
        } else {

            height = (CGFloat(generatedHeight)  + 1 ) * 100
        }

        return height
    }
```

I hope you will read and debug the code at your end and execute it.

Comment: thanks, but for every device number of rows may be different //for iphone 7 maybe 2..

Comment: From this function: setExpandedViewHeight I managed rows to be same in all devices, I hope you will never reject this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using autolayout then you can try this...

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = <estimatedRowHeight>;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

`UITableViewAutomaticDimension` will work if you've set leading, trailing, bottom, and top constraints relative to cell container view.

`estimatedRowHeight` : set this value with possible row height.

When you have set these properties, you neither need to implement `heightForRowAtIndexpath` nor `estimatedRowHeight`.